# How to find out exactly which column is causing error in a insert statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There is a insert statement with 100 columns. If it fails because length of one of the column is less than the value being inserted then we just get an error like

`ORA-1234: Value larger than the precision`

It becomes very difficult to find out which column out of those 100 is exactly causing this error. Why can't oracle display the exact column name which is causing this failure?

Comment: Well columns which are fixed width or don't have a width can be ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

When the column is a `NUMBER` then you can:

- Validate your data before you pass it to the `INSERT` statement.
- Ignore all the non-number columns and do a binary search on the `NUMBER` columns.

  - Delete half the columns/values in the `INSERT` and try it again.
  - If it succeeds then you know the error is in the other half of the columns/values.
  - If it fails then you know there is an error in this half of the columns/values.
  - Repeat removing successive halves until you narrow it down to a single column/value.

---

> Why can't oracle display the exact column name which is causing this failure?

It does tell you when the column is a `VARCHAR2` (and you would need to ask Oracle why they don't display a similar message for number columns).

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  col1 VARCHAR2(1),
  col2 VARCHAR2(2),
  col3 VARCHAR2(3)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES ('a', 'bbb', 'ccc');
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-12899: value too large for column "FIDDLE_SWAFVOYHEGSLZFRFYJTK"."TABLE_NAME"."COL2" (actual: 3, maximum: 2)
> ```

And, in PL/SQL:

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3)
  VALUES ('a', 'bbb', 'ccc');
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-12899: value too large for column "FIDDLE_OKWRWNCTGKRZMGUTOQIT"."TABLE_NAME"."COL2" (actual: 3, maximum: 2)
> ORA-06512: at line 2
> ```

or

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3)
  VALUES ('a', 'bbb', 'ccc');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN                 -- Don't catch OTHERS in production code
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-12899: value too large for column "FIDDLE_ZOMSITCUWOHNDCJIRVGC"."TABLE_NAME"."COL2" (actual: 3, maximum: 2)
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=986795806a81868a9b4971c6c2f335e3)*

Comment: It tells in case of VARCHAR column but not when the column is NUMBER